# What's the difference/relation between method, message and message passing?

Tags: oop

I recall hearing in youtube talks things like: "Messages define object behaviours", "Messaging is far more important concept of OOP than state", "design how your objects talk to each other through mocking", but from what I could find out, some OO languages do not support message passing, yet somehow I'm also guessing that messaging is much a broader concept and way of thinking rather than a language feature.

From what I could gather, the major difference between languages that do message passing (Ruby, Objective-C and Smalltalk) and those that do not (Java, C#, ...), is that on the first kind, one can send any message to any object, and then that object will internally chose to react to that message by dispatching it to some internal method, i.e. we never call a method directly, we just send a message to an object and the rest happens internally. 
Now, by convention the name of the message will be similar if not equal to the internal method name, thus sometimes providing the "illusion" that we're calling the methods directly on the object.

Objective-C has (to me) a weird syntax (said to have been copied from Smalltalk) so I could not understand much of the explanations with it, but I recall writes saying that on it, passing a message to an object which does not have an equivalent named public method doesn't even raise an exception, the message is simply ignored.

Is this understanding correct or not at all. Could you shed some more light into this and relate it to how this works or is applicable to (said) non-supporting languages like PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read what Alan Kay (the guy who came up with the term "object-oriented" programming) [says](http://wiki.c2.com/?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented), it seems that he values the messaging aspect very much to the point where he suggested that it should be called "message-oriented" programming.

He also underlines the importance of *late binding*. This is where the difference is I think to method calls. Messages are basically fire and forget things. They are not statically (early) bound, we are not sure whether the object can or should handle the message. Whereas method calls are usually used in static languages, where binding happens compile time.

It is still true in Java and C# that the "messages" between the objects, the interface or API of the objects is far more important than the internal structure. So we are still trying to do that for the most part.

Other than that, the question whether static binding or late binding can help systems grow better is an open question I think, although Alan Kay seems definitely on the late binding side (the messaging side) of this argument.